# DBHelper class cannot be instantiated (a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper) inside the same class

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I want to acess the database and insert data into the SQLite database.To acess the database i try to instatiate the DBHelper class i created extending the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class. The constructor of the  the `DBHelper`class is :

```
public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```

So I try to intatiate the class using this code

```
DBHelper myDb = new DBHelper(getContext());
```

It gives error saying "cannot resolve method getContext();"when `getContext()` function used as the argument for constructor of the `DBHelper` class.

The DBHelper class is as follows:

```
package com.violator.it17250_test1.Database;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import com.violator.it17250_test1.UserProfile;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
        "CREATE TABLE " + UserProfile.Users.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_NAME_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME + " TEXT," +
                UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_NAME_DOB + " TEXT, " +
                UserProfile.Users.COLUMN_NAME_GENDER + "TEXT )";

private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
        "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + UserProfile.Users.TABLE_NAME;


public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "users1.db";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

DBHelper myDb = new DBHelper(getContext());


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addInfo(){
    // Gets the data repository in write mode
    SQLiteDatabase db = myDb.getWritableDatabase();
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getContext()` is a method of the `View` class so you can use it like:  
`DBHelper myDb = new DBHelper(view.getContext());`  
where `view` is some `View`.  
If you want to instantiate the class inside an activity class you could use:

```
DBHelper myDb = new DBHelper(this);
```

or

```
DBHelper myDb = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: BHelper mydb = new DBHelper(view.getContext()); when used this, it gives an error saying "Cannot resolve symbol view"

Comment: Instead of `view` use any `View` in your activity.

Comment: When used View instead view it "Gives error Non-static method 'getContext()' cannot be referenced from a static context" Thank you!

Comment: Don't use `View` it is a class name. Use the name of a View in your activity, or just use `this`